# Is it possible to hide menu items in Emacs in a selective way?

Tags: emacs

I'd  like to sanitize the menus in Emacs since I consider some of the options in them to be noise. Is there a way to remove menu options selectively?

Comment: If you use the menu only rarely, you can enable/disable it with `menu-bar-mode` which can be called with `M-x`. That's what I do: turn it on to check for commands and then turn it off again when I'm done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Menus are just `keymap`s in Emacs.  See [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Modifying-Menus.html#Modifying-Menus)

A word of caution though -- I spent a lot of time thinking about how to get
menus exactly the way I want them in the beginning of my Emacs journey, but as
I used Emacs more, I found I never used menus as a part of my workflow.
Rarely, I would click on menus to get a quick overview of the feature
organization of a new package.

EDIT:

IMO it's not healthy to dwell on things that just don't matter, but if you
insist ... this is Emacs after all.  :)

Here is an e-mail [thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2009-02/msg00058.html) of someone asking this:

To remove psychotherapist:

```
(define-key menu-bar-help-menu [emacs-psychotherapist] nil)
```

Comment: Agree.. I only click menu when I go to unknown minefiled to get an overview of landmines.. that too at most a couple of time..

Comment: I also use mostly hot keys, but in the rare cases when I do use a menu it really annoys me to see all this junk like Emacs psychoterapist and Gnus launcher. Can you include an example of how one removes something from a menu?