# How to change/remove Emacs menu items?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, emacs23

I intend to change certain features/functions in Emacs. I'm familiar with different modes however my question is how certain functions are removed from the Graphical Interface - e.g. removing Games from Tools item in Menu bar or add new items to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hide menu items in Emacs in a selective way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667944/is-it-possible-to-hide-menu-items-in-emacs-in-a-selective-way)

Comment: how is this a security question?  Isn't this an emacs question?

Comment: @Arash why would emacs do anything related to access control?  Isn't that a problem for the operating system,  not an IDE?

Comment: @Arash, The tags are there to allow a user to filter for their area
of interest, mis-tagging questions makes the site less useful for everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add menu items with `define-key` or `define-key-after`. For example, to add a `Forward char` menu item at the start of the `Go To` submenu, you'd write:

```
(define-key (lookup-key global-map [menu-bar edit goto])
  [go-to-forward] '("Forward-char" . forward-char))
```

...and to put it after the `Goto Line...` item:

```
(define-key-after (lookup-key global-map [menu-bar edit goto])
  [go-to-forward] '("Forward char" . forward-char) 'go-to-line)
```

With this, and the info in the referred post, you should be able to change menus as you like.

As always, everything is documented: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Menu-Keymaps.html